# Are there similar theorems to the Infinite Monkey Typewriter Theorem?

Tags: probability

I was thinking about the [Infinite Monkey Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) and wondered if there’s any similar theorems but with a finite set? I know the infinite size is a critical assumption in the Monkey theorem, but are there any other results?

*UPDATE*: I realize now this question was badly worded and unclear, so I'll state it a bit more thoroughly:

Is there any finite-spaced results of the following form (loosely):

Given a finite sequence $\{x_1, x_2, ... x_N\}, N \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $X$ is some set is there any condition on $N$ being sufficiently large that we can say anything with high probability about the sequence?

Comment: Not really. Not unless you relax "similar" to the point where it isn't meaningful.  See the "almost surely" portion of that wiki page.

Comment: The link is not about a precisly stated  mathematical result. Perhaps you mean Borel's [Normal Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples)?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn’t.
Anything which is probabilistic and finite means that there is always the chance that the event that you want to occur won’t occur. Of course you could just make your set bigger, but that’d just be infinite all over again.

The best you can do is as follows: for any probability p<1, there exists N such that N monkeys all pressing k keys will almost surely (probability>p) type out any fixed k-length string (and by extension, anything shorter than length k). This means you could set p=99.99999%, and you could have a finite (although inconceivably large) cohort of monkeys which would produce what you want with at least probability p. Note: see library of babel.